# How to handle hyphens when writing to Redis using 'node-redis'?

Tags: node.js, redis

I have one NodeJS app that seems to work great. At the top:

```
  var redis = require('node-redis');
```

Then I fetch some data from a 3rd party feed, convert their XML to our JSON, then I:

```
        for (var i=0; i < books.length; i++) {
        var book = books[i];
        // Add a job to redis
        redisClient.publish("edison-nye", JSON.stringify(book));
        }
```

Everything seems great. If I log into Redis and run the MONITOR command, I can see all the data being written.

But then I created a second NodeJS app. This is going to subscribe to the channel that the first app publishes to.

So the second app:

```
  var redis = require('node-redis');

  var redisClient = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_PORT, process.env.REDIS_HOST, process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD);

  redisClient.subscribe("edison-nye");
```

Now I start seeing errors like this:

```
  [Error: winning journalist and the publisher of Bloomberg View. He has worked at the <I>New York Times</I>, the <I>Wall Street Journal</I>, <I>Talk </I>magazine, and the <I>Huffington Post</I>. O&rsquo;Brien edited a Pulitzer Prize&ndash;winning series on wounded war veterans in 2012 and is a recipient of the Gerald Loeb Award for Distinguished Business a
```

A lot more.

And:

```
  [SyntaxError: Unexpected token e]
```

When I look in the original data that was written to Redis, I see:

```
  \"authorbiocontact\":[\"<div>Timothy L. O&rsquo;Brien is an award-winning journalist and the publisher of Bloomberg View. He has worked at the <I>New York Times</I>, the <I>Wall Street Journal</I>, <I>Talk </I>magazine, and the <I>Huffington Post</I>.
```

So this hyphen was the problem:

```
  award-winning
```

and there are dozens of other examples.

So how am I suppose to handle hyphens when I write them to Redis?

[[ UPDATE ]]

the stack trace:

```
  at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/hasan/projects/ingestion_workers/node_modules/node-redis/index.js:227:13)
  at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:7)
  at EventEmitter.onError (/Users/hasan/projects/ingestion_workers/node_modules/node-redis/parser.js:365:10)
  at EventEmitter.onIncoming (/Users/hasan/projects/ingestion_workers/node_modules/node-redis/parser.js:130:16)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/hasan/projects/ingestion_workers/node_modules/node-redis/index.js:98:19)
  at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)
```

[[ UPDATE ]]
[[ UPDATE ]]

Interesting! It's not all hypens. I publish this:

```
  This fixed-layout ebook, which preserves the design and layout of the original print book, features read-along narration
```

I get this back:

```
  [Error: layout ebook, which preserves the design and layout of the original print book, features read-along narration.
```

So the first hyphen broke, but not the second one.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: I have now posted the stacktrace, but I am asking about hyphens.

Comment: Okay, I figured out part of why I was getting an error. The documentation I looked at was out of date. The modern function signature looks like this, (I tried to format this correctly, because it is code, but StackOverflow threw an error.) Among other problems, I was previously calling JSON.parse() on the channel name, and of course it is not an object, so it did not parse.

Comment: on('message', function (channel, message) {